# when use "&" operator in function pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

In the code below, I'm reading a `file.rec` in `main` and putting it in a `char buf`. Then I pass this `buf` and a function pointer for the `getCallBack()` function, but I pass the function on two available ways. This function so receives the function pointer normally in this two ways. So I'm interested to know what is the difference to use it or not.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void getCallBack(char buf[], void(*executeCallBack)(char[])){
    printf("callback recived\n");
    executeCallBack(buf);
}

void callBack(char buf[]){
    printf("executing callback...\n");
    printf("buf content: ");
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}

void main() {

    FILE *ReadingXmlFile = fopen("texto.rec", "r");
    char buf[10000];
    fread(buf, 1, 10000, ReadingXmlFile);
    fclose(ReadingXmlFile);

    printf("passing \"&callBack\"\n");
    getCallBack(buf, &callBack);

    printf("passing \"callBack\"\n");
    getCallBack(buf, callBack);
    //
}
```

Comment: A function naturally decays to a pointer to itself, similar to how an array decays to a pointer to its first element. I recommend being explicit about it though, and always use the address-of operator `&`.

Answer (score 4):

It is a purely cosmetic issue. In contexts where function type decays to pointer type by itself (which is almost everywhere), an explicit unary `&` makes no semantic difference. Choose what looks better to you. Just strive to be consistent.

---

Virtually the same thing applies to using explicit `*` operator when calling a function through a pointer. You can invoke your callback as `executeCallBack(buf)` or as `(*executeCallBack)(buf)`. The two are equivalent. Again, choose your style and stick to it.

Some might argue that just for the sake of symmetry, if you use `&` when obtaining the address, you should use `*` when calling the function.

Comment: So `sizeof callBack` is bad and `sizeof  &callBack` is good for the _other_ context?

Comment: @chux: I'm not sure I understand the question. What I said above about `&` applies only to contexts where its operand is of function type. If `callBack` itself is a pointer (not a function), then it is a different story - `&` makes a huge difference in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. The `&` is implied.

It's similar to the way that, if you have an array `someArray`, then `someArray` can be used instead of `&someArray[0]`.